# as little sensitive as possible

Tags: meaning, difference, adverbs, ambiguity, quantifiers

> a. I gave them as little sensitive information as possible.

Can't that sentence be read in two ways?

I think *little* could be modifying *sensitive* or *information*, so I see two possible readings:

> 1. The information I gave them was as little sensitive as possible.
> 2. I gave them the least possible amount of sensitive information.

Am I right?

Comment: It means that you gave them only the bare minimum of sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

In the phrase *as little information as possible*, the word *little* is a determiner that attaches to the noun *information*. It can't modify the adjective *sensitive*.

[Oxford Dictionary *little*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/little)

> [Determiner and Pronoun]
> 2. Used to emphasize how small an amount is.
> [as determiner] *I have little doubt of their identity*

[definition edited for format]

*Little* has uses as adjective, noun, adverb, pronoun and determiner. To modify an adjective like sensitive, it would have to be an adverb, but it isn't in this use. It's *little [sensitive information]*.

Comment: To modify "sensitive" you might use a word like "slightly": "I gave them some slightly sensitive information".